# Debugging deployed server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've encountered an issue that only occurs in one of our testing environments. It is unreproducible anywhere else. The webserver is sending the wrong data to the database. I've isolated the problem to the code behind file for a specific aspx page. Because the website is deployed to a testing server that doesn't have Visual Studio installed I can't attach to the process and step through the code behind file.

I've used fiddler to verify that the correct data is being sent by the browser to the web server. I've used SQL Profiler to verify that the database is receiving data that is already corrupt, so the database isn't corrupting the data.

Given that I can't attach to the process in this testing environment, are there any other debugging tools or techniques that I can use that don't involve redeploying the site?

Comment: Can you install the remote debugging agent?

Comment: Either what @SLaks said or you can add logging on your app and use that to log the data before they are sent to the DB. nLog, log4Net, seriLog, they all the same job so take you pick.

Comment: I wouldn't rule it out completely but it's unlikely. My only way to access the webserver is via a special ID that I have to checkout in emergencies certified by the client. But I'll look into it.

Comment: Well then your options are limited. Either perform remote debugging or add logging as suggested by @Liran's answer and redeploy the application. Why do you think you can't reproduce it?

Comment: What's happening is a server side <select> control always sends the first <option> in the list in this one environment. In every other environment it sends the selected <option>. Apparently this has happened before and mysteriously resolved itself. The affected environment is shared with other groups, but I don't know what environment settings would affect the way .NET reads the selected value of a drop down list.